# How to setup dedicated Sidekiq server?

Tags: redis, sidekiq, dedicated-server

I have a rails app which deployed on 2 ec2 instance with nginx and capistrano. For background job, I had used sidekiq with redis. I have 50 gb memory on server. I also have set max_pool_size to 50 of sidekiq concurrency. I want use one instance as a dedicated server for Sidekiq. How shall I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to have a Rails app and a Sidekiq server. You can have a Rails app that connects to an instance which also has a copy of your Rails app and a Sidekiq server. The only thing you'd have to do on the Sidekiq server is not run rails but instead only run sidekiq.

In my opinion, you're complicating things by wanting it like this. You're better having both on the same server and have a separate ElasticCache Redis server running to which your Sidekiq can connect.